# Custom font Ionic 2

Tags: css, ionic2, font-face

So I'm trying to use a custom font in my Ionic 2 app and for some reason it's displaying something that is not correct.

My font is GothamRounded, so I copy all .ttf, .svg, .otf and .eot files inside the www/fonts folder in my Ionic project.

Then, inside app.component.scss (my main component) I wrote this:

```
app {

  @font-face {
    font-family: GothamRounded;
    src: url($font-path + "/GothamRounded-Book.ttf");
  }

  font-family: GothamRounded;

}
```

Now, when my app is reloaded, my font has changed, and if I inspect an element with text inside I can see this in dev console:

```
app {
    font-family: GothamRounded;
}
```

But the text displayed has a seriff, and my font doesn´t, so I'm guessing this is not actually getting the real font.

Any idea what might be happening?
Thanks

Comment: generally resources go to src/assets folder. Your font should be in src/assets/fonts folder and set `src: url('./assets/fonts/GothanRounded-Book.ttf')`.Also what is $font-path?

Comment: $font-path is precisely a variable defined in variables.scss ```$font-path: "../assets/fonts";```

Comment: try with `./assets/fonts` This path works for me for images.. a double dot means parent folder

Comment: and copy the font to src/assets it will be copied to your www/assets during the build

Comment: the path is ../, so that is correct; also, the fonts are already copied in the folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why the app selector? is it just for showing us the code or you really have an app tag somewhere in you code? For me it's `<ion-app>`

Try setting the src to all your font extensions and using the format in front of it like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: GothamRounded;
  src: url($font-path + "/GothamRounded-Book.ttf") format('ttf'), url($font-path + "/GothamRounded-Book.otf") format('otf'), ...;
}
```

I'm using a custom font too and mine wasn't working inside any other .scss file that wasn't the app.scss file, so inside my app.scss i have this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Humanst';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/humanst-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../assets/fonts/humanst-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Humanst' !important;
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems that the trick was the format woff, I included that and everything worked fine as it was. Your answer actually fixed the problem so thanks!

Comment: glad it helped :D

Comment: On variables.scss you can override the variable $font-family-base.

Answer (score 0):

```css
$regular:'MuseoSans-500';
$bold:'MuseoSans-700';
@each $font-face in $regular,
$bold {
  @font-face {
    font-family: $font-face;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/#{$font-face}.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/#{$font-face}.eot?') format('eot'),
    url('../assets/fonts/#{$font-face}.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../assets/fonts/#{$font-face}.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../assets/fonts/#{$font-face}.svg##{$regular}') format('svg');
  }
}
```

This is helpful if you want to add multiple fonts.