# How to add custom font family in ionic2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to add new font family from Google fonts in my ionic2 app. I need to change the default font family and add my custom font family. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom font Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932096/custom-font-ionic-2)

Comment: Hi, you can follow this https://github.com/yannbf/ionicCustomIconsSample/blob/master/src/theme/variables.scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this link https://chriztalk.com/using-google-fonts-ionic-2/. It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to make sure the 'font-family' name matches the native fonts name.To check the font's name in Windows you can just double click the .ttf file and see what value 'Font name' has.

Lets say I have a font I want to use in my Ionic app and I check it's .ttf file and it's font name is 'Flouc Font'. I would make sure the .ttf is in the correct folder (assets/fonts) in my case. Then edit the `/src/theme/variables.scss` file to include the following definition:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flouc Font";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/floucFont.ttf")
}

*{
  font-family: "Flouc Font";
}
```